# Chrome doesn't let me scroll with my mouse wheel

Tags: scrolling

I just upgraded to Windows 10 (with Chrome as my browser) but just like when I was using Windows 7, I still can't use the mouse wheel to scroll up/down. I used to be able to click on a page, then turn the wheel to move a page up/down.

What I actually have to do now is to click on a blank area of any page, let the star shaped thing  appear, then move the mouse up or down a bit and the page automatically moves. The wheel does absolutely nothing.

I have tried all the remedies given by the experts (uninstall/re-install Google Chrome, incognito mode, etc.), I hope some simple guidance from any of you people can help  fix my scrolling issue.

Comment: Does disabling hardware acceleration in Chrome settings help?